# problems implementing bilingual 2 columns using reledpar / reledmac

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

I am a LaTeX newbie experimenting with reledpar/reledmac.  I hope it is not rude or inefficient to ask so many questions in one post.  I suspect the answers are interrelated.  I have only recently installed LaTeX on my (fairly new) Mac so all my packages are up-to-date.

I want to produce some **lecture notes** teaching ancient Greek to an Arabic audience who also need sections in English.

Mostly  will need  2-columns (Greek / Arabic) with footnotes notes(Greek on the left, Arabic on the right).  But there are also occasional separate paragraphs and footnotes in English and Arabic (both entire paragraphs and footnotes).

The example in the reledpar documentation (`3-reledpar_columns_different_languages`) looks really close to what I want.  The MWE I pasted below, and the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neWW0.png) is based directly on it, and I have tried to modify it unsuccessfully.

I have encountered many minor problems that I cannot solve, even though I've looked through the `reledpar` and `reledmac` documentation.
Here are the list of problems:

1. Some of the text in the top is not displaying in Arabic, even though the right-column is.
2. I don't understand why `\begin{RTL}` is required: I thought `polyglossia` took care of that.
3. An Arabic sentence is not displaying in Arabic shortly under the make title command.  But if I use polyglossia's `begin{Arabic}...end{Arabic}` worse problems occur.
4. The two columns bump into each other, even though the columns add up to 0.95 of `\textwidth`.  If I specify `\sloppy` it helps to some degree, but still strange.
5. Can the critical note streams (note 8 and 4) appear on the left and right of the same line to save vertical space?  Very often a critical note in the Arabic will correspond to a critical note in the Greek.
6. The numbering of the section title seems strange.  On the left it is 0.1, on the right 1.0.  I want line numbers for the parallel text, but not for the section title
7. The numbering of the parallel text seems strange: line 1 is blank for both Greek and Arabic!

Finally, I also suspect that my `\usepackage` statements are confused.  For example, `fontspec` appears twice, but if I remove one the Tex won't compile.

Thank you for any help.

Tim

Following  is the MWE (or moderately-working-example).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}  
\usepackage[a4paper, xetex]{geometry}  
\usepackage{fontspec}  
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}  
\usepackage{metalogo,hyperref}  
\usepackage{polyglossia, fontspec, xunicode}  
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}  
\usepackage[series={A,B},noend,noledgroup]{reledmac}  
\usepackage{reledpar}   
%\numberlinefalse  
\setRlineflag{}  
\linenumincrement*{1}  
\firstlinenum*{1}  
\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.35\textwidth}  
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.6\textwidth}   

\setmainlanguage{english}  
\setotherlanguage{greek}  
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}  
\setotherlanguage{arabic}  

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.3]{Scheherazade}  
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew, Scale = 1.3]{Linux Libertine O}  
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Scale = 1.1]{Linux Libertine O}  
\begin{document}  
\title{Parallel columns in two different languages}  

{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}  
Some introductory text in English  
أفاق إختار والفلبين لان تم. جيما أراضي نفس أي, ٣٠ بحث  
\begin{pairs}  
\begin{Rightside}   
\begin{RTL}  
\begin{Arabic}  
\beginnumbering  
\pstart  
\section{بالرغم}\ledleftnote{A}  
\pend  
\pstart  

هو شمال وسمّيت هذه, وسمّيت الأرضية قام كل. بـ فعل الأرض الإمداد. السيء طائرات ستالينجراد، ثم كلّ, مع معركة الأمريكي، جعل, أن بداية اتّجة والنازي حرب. أن ربع وتنصيب استعملت \edtext{مثل}{\Bfootnote{وحلفاؤها يكن }} أن ولم مسارح انتباه واقتصار, جهة كل لعدم فرنسية عشوائية, بـ نقطة والفلبين قام. عن العناد بالمحور تشيكوسلوفاكيا يكن. أم إعلان ليركز ضرب. دنو لم تحرير الطرفين استطاعوا, إحتار وحلفاؤها يكن قد.  
, ربع أي بولندا نورماندي. قد عرض مشاركة البشريةً بريطانيا،, فقد ان صفحة إستراتيجية. اللازمة والكوري به، أم.  


\pend     
\endnumbering  
\end{Arabic}  
\end{RTL}  
\end{Rightside}  

\begin{Leftside}   
\begin{greek}  
\beginnumbering  
\pstart  
\section{Sample Answer}     
\pend   
\pstart  
Σεδ σασε σλιτα περπετυα υθ? Μωδω φυισετ ιν σεα. Αλιι ιυσθο σιθ συ, ευμ αλιι λωρεμ ινσωλενς υθ. Ελιτρ λυσιλιυς χενδρεριτ νες ετ, νυλλα σωνσεκυαθ μει νο, λιβερ σριπθα σιθ αν. Αν ιυς λαβωρε\edtext{φυισετ}{\Bfootnote{This means something}} εφερθιθυρ σομπλεσθιθυρ! Ηας εα υβικυε απεριαμ φολυπθυα, μαγνα τιβικυε ασεντιορ ευ σιθ. Δεβετ μυσιυς ασυεφεριθ φελ εα, ατ παρτεμ γραεσι υλλαμσορπερ ευμ?  
\pend  
\endnumbering  
\end{greek}  
\end{Leftside}  

\end{pairs}  
\Columns  

This is some more 1-column text.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, inani eirmod blandit pro ut, eu errem urbanitas reformidans! Vim no unum vocent, tota adhuc vocent\footnoteA{I think this is true} ea has! His paulo scribentur ea! In mel mucius facilisi facilisis, vide falli persequeris ius ea! Per erat ferri ea, alia doming ceteros ex duo. Ei eam dolor suscipit, ei duo ferri adolescens. Mea nobis oratio an, labore viderer ad qui!  

\end{document}
```

Comment: For  shortly Arabic sentence  under the make title put it as argument of `\textarabic{}`, same thing with arabic   sentence inside `\section`

Comment: Regarding to texts overlap between columns i think be due to there is no hyphenation for greek, a trick to  solve this (but they do not give a nice view) is to add `\tolerance=10000` in the preamble

Comment: 1) not related to reledmac/reledpar. I can't answer.

Comment: 2) that is because of internal implementation of reledpar. 3) not related to reledmac/reledpar 4) thats is problem of overfull hbox. Only two solution : use sloppy or change columns witdh 5) for now, it is not possible in reledpar, and honestly, I have no time to implement such feature, quite complex 6 and 7) use optional argument of \pstart to use \section inside. Cf http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/examples/2-titles_not_in_line_numbering.tex

Comment: Thank you so much!  I used the `\tolerance` command successfully.

Comment: Thank you so much @salimbou!  I used the `\tolerance` command successfully.  The `\textarabic` command was less successful, since the phrase is left-aligned, not right-aligned.  Any ideas?  [result](http://i.imgur.com/f26HdHj.png) Thank you also @Maïeul, but your example breaks down when using 2 columns as you can see the left hand is numbered 1.1 and the right hand is numbered 1.2, and I want them to have the same number, obviously.  Any ideas?  Maybe I should just live with the numbered text titles!

Comment: Actually, the real problem seems to be the interaction between Reledpar and Polyglossia.  I can take @Maïeul's documented example which works fine using Hebrew; but if I switch to Arabic it suddenly doesn't work.  This is no longer a matter of numbering or alignment.  Where should I investigate further?  Is it a problem with Reledpar?  Or its use of polyglossia?

Comment: @Tim : I need a MWE to understand what doest not work.

Comment: @Tim : you could read maybe http://geekographie.maieul.net/137. For the problem if section numbering, you are right. I have corrected it in branch "issue391" in github. Please try it and make feedback.